# Intel Will be Sponsoring DevOps SE

Tags: discussion, featured, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that Intel will be sponsoring DevOps Stack Exchange, April 2nd through June 29th. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what it will look like.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown on the right side of the header at the top of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: Image of DevOps SE home page with Intel sponsorship logo]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it! If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

And lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making this site successful.